# How to add a delay to JmsMessage for Artemis Broker in Spring Integration Outbound Adapter

Tags: spring-integration, activemq-artemis

I have a jms outbound channel adapter. I would like to send a message to my Apache Artemis Broker and add a delay.

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="scheduledConnectionFactory" channel="tnpScheduledOutboundChannel" destination="tnpScheduledQueue" />
```

My java code that adds the header to the spring integration message is:

```
 return MessageBuilder.withPayload(sdpInfo).setHeader("_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY",sdpInfo.getDelay()).build();
```

The header is added as a spring integration header. But its not picked up by JMS i.e the consumer of the queue sees it instantly.

Do I need to add some kind of JmsHeaderMapper? Could someone point to some documentation or example.

***Update***

This is the message caught at debug in the JmsSendingMessageHandler.

```
ActiveMQMessage[null]:PERSISTENT/ClientMessageImpl[messageID=0, durable=true, address=null,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[sequenceNumber=4,file_status=0,sequenceSize=0,_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY=14685858,timestamp=1605707114145,correlationId=4d6fa6c8-fdcb-d69b-cd60-d260264545f5]]
```

If I use directly in an activator a jmsTemplate

```
public void sendDelayMessage(SdpInfoTemplate<?> message, long deliveryDelay, String queue) {
        jmsTemplateDelay.setDeliveryDelay(deliveryDelay);
        jmsTemplateDelay.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        jmsTemplateDelay.convertAndSend("sdp-file-tnp-scheduled-dimitris-test", message, m -> {
            m.setLongProperty("_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", deliveryDelay);
            m.setStringProperty("TRANSACTION_ID",message.getTransactionId());
            return m;
        });
```

Key part being `jmsTemplateDelay.setDeliveryDelay(deliveryDelay);`

It will be scheduled if I dont set this it is ignored and the consumer side picks up the message immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` is used in the `JmsSendingMessageHandler` by default. It maps all the headers into `jmsMessage.setObjectProperty(propertyName, value);` if the values are in the supported types:

```
private static final List<Class<?>> SUPPORTED_PROPERTY_TYPES = Arrays.asList(new Class<?>[] {
        Boolean.class, Byte.class, Double.class, Float.class
```

Or you lose that your header somewhere in between...

**UPDATE**

Sorry, but you are confusing us. Your `_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` is indeed present as a property in that final JMS message. When you talk about `setDeliveryDelay()`, it is fully different story.

What you can do is something like extension for the `DynamicJmsTemplate`. Override its `getDeliveryDelay()` and take the required value from a `ThreadLocal` you populate before sending message to that `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

This is something we definitely can add into the `DynamicJmsTemplate` and `DynamicJmsTemplateProperties` to be addressed by the mentioned `JmsSendingMessageHandler`. But at the moment the workaround only implementing your own `ThreadLocal` variable for this `deliveryDelay` option.

Comment: I have updated my answer i dont seem to lose my header. Also if i use directly a jmsTemlpate and I dont `jmsTemplateDelay.setDeliveryDelay(deliveryDelay);` the message is sent immediately

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Calculation of time in millis was wrong i was passing only the difference, There is no need to add setDeliveryDelay which boils down to `_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` itself

Answer (score 0):

For this setup (Spring Integration + Artemis) if you want to delay message delivery to consumer, you could do

```
.setHeader(Message.HDR_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_TIME.toString(), System.currentTimeMillis() + {yourDelayInMs})
```

The key point is that you should set time of delivery in ms from epoch, instead of actual delay value.